# Is it possible to download Google Chrome 32bits on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: google-chrome

I tried to download it on [the official Google Chrome Website](https://www.google.ca/chrome/browser/desktop/) but the only version are 64 bits. My question is the title, is it possible to download Chrome 32bits?

English isnt my first language sorry for mistakes, Thanks you!

Comment: Google does not offer a 32bit version of Chrome for Linux any more. There are 32bit versions for other operating systems like Windows, but the Linux version only comes in 64bit.

Answer (score 2):

Google discontinued it.But you can still install it. Trying "Chromium" is better? They r the same.

Comment: There is a notable difference if you switch to Chromium: the Widevine decryption module is gone, so Netflix and some similar sites won't work.

Comment: Please provide a little more information about how to do this in your answer.  A little step by step that the OP can follow would be ideal :)